# Validate.js not displaying errors

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

So I'm using [Validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/) to validate my forms through the front-end. But for some weird reason the errors are not being displayed. I'm also not sure if they're being validated to begin with. Any ideas?

Heres my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
  <script>
var validator = new FormValidator('form1', [{
    name: 'name',
    display: 'required',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'email',
    rules: 'valid_email'
}, {
    name: 'password',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'password_confirm',
    display: 'password confirmation',
    rules: 'required|matches[password]'
}], function(errors, event) {
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        // Show the errors
    }
});
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Nothing is displaying. @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation in the validate.js page:

```
The formName passed in to validate must be the exact value of the name attribute of the form
```

You are using the id of the form instead of the name in the `validator` variable. You need to add a name to your form and use it in your variable:

```
<form id="form1" name="myForm">
[...]
<script>
var validator = new FormValidator('myForm', [{
[...]
```

Hope it helps!